# "Update Altitude" does not work on TCX Converter

Tags: convert, google-earth, altitude

I have downloaded TCX Converter from the official site.

Although I update altitude data of points which I created from Google Earth, they can't be displayed on table. Only "ml>" is written on altitude(ALT) field instead of integer values.

Why does it happen?(Problematic area is shown in red frame.) ([image])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me; in the beginning TCX worked perfectly but suddenly the same thing  happend to me  so i tried this; after saving your .kml file from google earth, go to http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/elevation and load the file there. Click "Convert and Add Elevation," and output as a .gpx file. Download the link that it gives you and import that into TCX Converter. Do not update elevation, only export as a .csv file and continue from there, opening in excel, but after this and  amazingly  TCX "repented" and the update command worked again